# Azure Service Fabric deployments consume a lot disk space

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I operate an on-premise Azure Service Fabric cluster for testing purposes. It consists of three nodes, which are running on a single virtual machine (Windows Server 2012) with a 50 GB disk attached to it.

Further I set up continuous deployment from TFS release pipeline to the cluster. However after approx. 80 deployments, service fabric consumed all available disk space and further deployments fail.

Most of the space is taken by C:\ProgramData\SF\Data, which took around 28GB, while each code package has a size of ~130 MB. After I have unprovisioned many of the old deployments (manually via SF portal), only around 5GB were released. Many of the old files are still around in C:\ProgramData\SF\Data.

What is the best approach to improve this?

- Why are the files from the old deployments still on disk after unprovisioning?
- Is it possible to delete these files manually?
- Is it possible to automate the deprovisioning?

On a production environment this situation should be relaxed anyhow (since there is only one node per machine and bigger disks). Nevertheless this would only put off the evil day. I would feel safer to avoid this situation at all.

### Edit

It seems that SF is deleting the deployment packages with some delay. I checked the test cluster after one day, and all unprovisioned packages vanished finally.

Comment: Can you provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that SF is deleting the deployment packages with some delay. I checked the test cluster after one day, and all unprovisioned packages vanished finally.

Further I found the **Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType** Cmdlet to automate the unprovisioning process (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125885.aspx).

Comment: Still, shouldn't this sort of disk management task be handled by the fabric? It should know it has X old versions of an app that are not used and that it can drop all but the last few, right? I don't want to have to manage disk space on my clusters when the fabric could easily take this on.